# Teamcity: Agent side checkout causing commit not to be found error

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gradle, teamcity

When I try setting up a git project build that uses 'Agent Side Checkout' for VCS Checkout mode (based on build template), the build is failing saying a particular commit is not found. But that very commit is in gerrit waiting to be code reviewed. If I change the checkout mode to Server, then teamcity is able to find that commit. Can someone explain to me as why this is happening and what can be done to make it work with agent side checkout mode?